# Valor incorrecto en publicaciones totales a la espera de revisión

Tags: bug

El número de *publicaciones totales a la espera de revisión* no coincide con las publicaciones que aparecen en la cola de revisión.

Una imagen vale más que mil palabras...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En esta pregunta se habla sobre el tema que mencionas, http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/837/por-qu%C3%A9-me-aparecen-tareas-pendientes

Comment: Gracias @Juan. :)